# Element type is invalid in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have used following code in react-native code that code are there:

header.js file code==

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
const Header = () => {
    const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;
    return (
        <View style={viewStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>Photography</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
const styles = {
    viewStyle: {
        backgroudColor: '#F8F8F8',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 60,
        paddingTop: 14
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontSize: 20
    }
};
export default Header;
```

app.js file code ==

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native'; 
const App = () => (     <Text>Some Text</Text> );
AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

I get following error in emulator[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMpqp.png)

How to solved this error please tell me to how to remove that error please anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would have an index.js file containing only:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

...then in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...
import Header from './header';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
...
render() {
   return(
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Header />
     </View>
   )
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
 },
...
}
```